# Install Android Studio Canary on Manjaro: Problems with KVM

Tags: android-studio, kvm, manjaro

I wanted to install Android Studio and I stumbled onto following issue:

The Installer of Android Studio wouldn't progress further after the summary because of this Message:

[image: Android message]

So I researched and knew that I had to install qemu and kvm - no problem I thought.

So I installed qemu and all the stuff. I did the pretests if my System is able to run and enable kvm: it is.

I also enabled the Virtualization in BIOS, so that cant be the problem.

`virtsh list`

also, works.

I also restarted the kvm modules with

```
sudo rmmod kvm_intel
sudo rmmod kvm

sudo modprobe kvm
sudo modprobe kvm_intel
```

So what am I missing?

I'm adding a Screenshot of a few Commands that I found for troubleshooting.

[image: Commands for troubleshooting]

Thanks for any Help!

I'm running Manjaro 17.0.1, x86_64, trying to install Android Studio Canary Preview

Comment: I would check the AUR. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/android-studio-canary/ and wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android

Comment: Thank you!
I tried to install the AUR package with yaourt, but it ended up with the same result.
I will try to install everything manually step by step with the Arch Wiki

Comment: Hmm. The KVM / Qemu wiki pages could also help